# node server is starting automatically and can't be killed

Tags: node.js, windows

### Environment

1. Windows 10 Pro
2. PATH setting:

   C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\ (v0.10.13)

   C:\Program Files\nodejs (v6.2.2)
3. node version global: v6.2.2
4. npm version : 3.9.5

### Description

I installed node.js, and right after installation I got problem because nodejs starting background process taking port 8080 which must not be taken.

running command:

```
>netstat -ano | find "8080"
TCP    0.0.0.0:8080           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4428
```

running command:

```
>taskkill /IM "node.exe" /T /F
SUCCESS: The process with PID 6140 (child process of PID 4428) has been terminated.
SUCCESS: The process with PID 2916 (child process of PID 2776) has been terminated.
SUCCESS: The process with PID 10888 (child process of PID 2776) has been terminated.
SUCCESS: The process with PID 4428 (child process of PID 2556) has been terminated.
SUCCESS: The process with PID 2776 (child process of PID 2560) has been terminated.

>netstat -ano | find "8080"
```

But after some time server is started again:

```
>netstat -ano | find "8080"
TCP    0.0.0.0:8080           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       11052
```

Looked up startup applications, services and scheduled tasks, found nothing containing node or npm.

Also found no info on this event in application logs of mmc console.

What part of windows system can cause startup of node server?

How can I change this default port for node server?

Also noticed that if i'll start some other process and bind it to 8080 right after killing node.exe processes, then node trying to: [start new process and connect to 8080]----{fail}---->[retry attempt].

Task manager displays 2 node.exe processes on port 8000 and 8080. Get request on those ports result in "Cannot get /". All processes of node pointing to  C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\ (v0.10.13).

**SOLVED**

Don't know why exactly, but it seems that version v0.10.13 of node which (was installed along with aptana studio 3) has some sort of service, which wasn't easily visible in service list and which was causing the trouble. Removal of this old version of node removed server instances from processes.

Comment: How did you start the node server? As per my knowledge you need to create a node server and bind it to a port through javascript code. Did you write some code for it?

Comment: no code added, thats why it a problem. I looked all internet tutorials i could find about node server and how to start it, but none telling that node server starting by itself without config. I got this computer from previous owner, cleaned up everything I could but can't solve this particular problem. Even after node reinstall problem remains. Can't spot the place where could be script placed in windows which do described thing but not displayed in task manager. 
Looked up all npm catalogs and package.json -> no info about server config.

Comment: Maybe you have installed some app build with node which starts a server in background.

Comment: if I remove nodejs, nothing taking port 8080 and all apps still working except aptana studio 3, but still I don't think it's aptana fault:

    1. I we're not using aptana during current session
    2. aptana should not have node server started in backgroud on windows startup. Server instance must be configured in IDE, am I wrong?

Comment: Could it be some windows registry values responsible for starting node server?